# Google AdWords API v201802: fields selector not working with python libraries

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am connecting to Google AdWords via API v201802 and most recent Python3 googleads module. The connection works fine and I can retrieve data for Campaigns or Ad Groups but the fields selector seems not to work. I'd like to request only a few fields, but I receive all available fields. Am I overlooking something?

```
from googleads import adwords

adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
ad_group_service = adwords_client.GetService('AdGroupService', version='v201802')
selector = {
    'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'CampaignId'],
    'paging': {
        'startIndex': '0',
        'numberResults': '500'
    }
}
page = ad_group_service.get(selector)
print(page)
```

Result:

```
{
    'totalNumEntries': 138,
    'Page.Type': 'AdGroupPage',
    'entries': [
        {
            'id': 44831117552,
            'campaignId': 888843682,
            'campaignName': None,
            'name': '001_0001_BMM_xxx',
            'status': 'ENABLED',
            'settings': [],
            'labels': [],
            'forwardCompatibilityMap': [],
            'biddingStrategyConfiguration': None,
            'contentBidCriterionTypeGroup': None,
            'baseCampaignId': None,
            'baseAdGroupId': None,
            'trackingUrlTemplate': None,
            'finalUrlSuffix': None,
            'urlCustomParameters': None,
            'adGroupType': None,
            'adGroupAdRotationMode': None
        },
        ...
    ] }
```

Of course I can filter out the unneeded fields when processing the response, but I wonder why the fields selector is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer to this in [adwords-api google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-api/selectors$20not$20working%7Csort:date/adwords-api/3uj0WXcEX_U/_LTcFPe6GRQJ):

> Hi Kevin,
>
> The API will always include the fields your are requesting in the
>   response, but it might also add other fields that will be grouped
>   together to some of your original fields.
>
> Best,
>
> David Torres - AdWords API Team